# Need Help Adding a UV Mapping on my Dragon for Unreal Engine

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, uv-image-editor, unreal-engine

I'm to unwrap my dragon model in order to add a UV mapping on it, but the mesh so complex that it's actually making Blender crash if I do the *entire* model. **Basically**, I'm trying to unwrap the model, but also have it displayed where it is easiest for me to understand and I would like figure out how to place it over where I have colored the model. I already UVed the eyes, and the wings and body are separate meshes (so are the eyes and gums and teeth, but they're merged with the body mesh).

Here's the Blender file

[image]

Here's a photo of the dragon (normal and wire mode)
[image: Full Mesh Wire and Normal]

Comment: Hello, I have tried and did not have any problem unwrapping the body. However, in order to have a good UV map, you may mark seams on your model (like if your mesh was a cloth from which you mark the seewing).

Comment: I tried making seams but it seems to make it even harder to see the mappings (I tried this on the wings)

Comment: For some reason, I can't seem to get the UV textures to display on the mesh.. rendering doesn't help it either